# How to make controls stretch and shrink when the window is resized?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I make it when the window is resized none of the controls are on one corner or just shrug away but become bigger or smaller to correspond with the window In Windows forms?

Comment: `WPF` or `WindowsForms` ?

Comment: @FelixD. Maybe they're doing MVC and want it on a web page? ;)

Comment: Im using windows forms

Comment: @krillgar I assume it's one of them .. :D when it comes to MVC most ppl have some experience on .Net :D

Comment: @LogandadLoga is this solved ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to `Anchor` your control(s) on the window.

Basically u (always) anchor your control on `Top` & `Left` (that's default anyway).

If you want to stretch your `Control` horizontal add `Right`.
For vertical stretching add `Bottom`.

**[Properties]** (rightclick the control you want to anchor and select properties)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use **Anchor** property of each control to achieve the effect.

For example, if you set it to "Right, Bottom" on a control, it will keep its right and bottom side anchored (set to fixed distance) against the right and bottom edge of the form.

This is sufficient for basic sizing. For advanced sizing, you have to size your controls manually on window resize event.

You might also want to set **MinimumSize** property of your form to prevent its window to shrink under that size. This way you can prevent unwanted layout distortions like controls clipped or completely hidden behind right or bottom edge of the window.